# How to add style to GeoServer through REST API

Tags: javascript, geoserver-rest-api

Let imagine. the style content is like below CSS code.

```
[status = 'Layih&#x259;']{
  fill: #e1e1e1;
}

[type = 'Sahil'] {
    fill: #6f9bcc;      
  [@sd < 6k]{
    stroke: #3235ff;
    fill: url("https://imgur.com/BdQQhxA.png");             
    fill-mime: "image/png";
  };

}`
```

I can not add the content of style to geoserver. It only creates a style name and style file name. Could you please help?

```
   await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW46Qm94eUFzdHJpZDYzMTk=',
        },
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sde/styles',
        data: {
            style: {
                name: 'style_clone',
                filename: 'style_clone.css',
            }
        }

    })
        .then(
            response => {
                return res.status(201).json(response.data);
            },
        ).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            return res.status(500).json(error);
        });;
```

Comment: can you add the actual URL of the request? and any error messages from the GeoServer log file

Comment: I did, There is no error. It creates but the issue is the content of style file is empty. I wanna learn how to add the content of style to created file in GeoServer

Comment: I think your format is wrong and you need to append `?raw=true` to the end of the URL

Comment: okey I append. But where should I add style content?

Comment: you set the content type as  'Content-type': 'application/json', - it is not json that you are sending

Comment: Okay thanks, I can upload, update SLD file type. But I can not still create and update any CSS style type. What should be content-type for CSS? Unfortunately, there is no tutorial for that.

I have tried that:

curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/css" -d @data_clone.css http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sde/styles/style_clone.css